# How to copy table content before deleting to flat file using BCP

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, bcp

I have created stored procedure where, I delete data in any given time. I want to save the records to a flat file before deleting in case I need to import the data back to table.
I DO NOT want to call from the command line as I have a program that calls the stored procedure to schedule the job.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Clean] ( 
 @DeletionDate date
) AS

DECLARE @id int,
    @intError int

        DELETE FROM 
      Errn 
     WHERE 
    erid IN (
         select 
             distinct m.ID
         from 
             Member m
         left join 
             (select 
                  *, row_number() over (PARTITION BY rid order by ceid desc) 
           as rn
              from TypeA) x 
             on m.ID = x.ID and x.rn = 1
           where 
             (
                 (x.ceid is null and m.DateTime < @Deletion) 

             );
     ON_ERROR:
     RETURN @intError
    RETURN 0
```

How can I copy the results of the select statement to a .txt file before deleting the records?

Comment: [OUTPUT clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is one way, but I'm confused as to what you are doing here. Why the cursor? You are running the same `DELETE` over and over again and aren't using the cursor for anything other than a counter. Should it be `where rid = @ID`? If so, you still don't need a cursor for this. This RBAR method can be done in a single statement unless I'm missing something here.

Comment: @ scsimon this was just an example. changed it, and as I mentioned in my question I need to use bcp to copy the deleted records into .txt file.. in the link you mentioned I can't find how to copy to file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to write to a file, you can still use `ouput.deleted` with `bcp queryout`.

```
create table #mytable (id int)
insert into #mytable
values
(1),(2),(3)

create table ##deleted (id int)

delete from #mytable
output deleted.* into ##deleted
where id = 2


declare @cmd varchar(1000) = 'bcp "select id from ##deleted" queryout "E:\TEST\deleted.txt" -t, -c -T'
print @cmd
EXEC master..XP_CMDSHELL @cmd  

select * from #mytable
select * from ##deleted

drop table ##deleted, #mytable
```

I wouldn't do this *before* the delete... because what if the delete fails? You wouldn't want to log records as deleted when they actually didn't.

Comment: I see your point, but I don't know how to avoid the situation. Although I'm sure that I would run to such situation in some point

Answer (score 1):

As scsimon has pointed out, you can take advantage of OUTPUT clause instead of using a flat file.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(id int identity, foo int);
CREATE TABLE MyTableDeleted(id int, foo int);

INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES
(100),(200),(300),(400),(500);
```

```
DELETE FROM
    MyTable
OUTPUT
    DELETED.* INTO MyTableDeleted
WHERE
    foo <= 300;
```

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable;
```

> ```
> id | foo
> -: | --:
>  4 | 400
>  5 | 500
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM MyTableDeleted;
```

> ```
> id | foo
> -: | --:
>  1 | 100
>  2 | 200
>  3 | 300
> ```